# How to regenerate an old React native project from source files (JSX files)?

Tags: react-native

I have a 2 year old React Native project that I need to modify a bit and rebuild the apk file. It uses old libraries and RN version 0.63.2 . I only have the source code(JSX files) and package.json. What is the best way to rebuild this? I tried to init a new project and just using the source files there but it doesn't work (Android folder doesnt get detected).